# How to programmatically enable Location on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, gps, location

Is there a way to programmatically enable Location on Windows 10 using c#.NET winforms. I am able to get coordinates using the following code unless the user's Location is off.

```
        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher.StatusChanged += Watcher_StatusChanged;
        watcher.Start(false);


    private void Watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
            {
                if (!watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
                {
                    latitude = watcher.Position.Location.Latitude;
                    longitude = watcher.Position.Location.Longitude;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Location");
        }
    }
```

Comment: isn't the whole _point_ of turning off the location to _prevent_ code getting access to the location?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann  That is true, but suppose we need it for our own workgroup who keep moving from place to place and we need to track them.

Comment: thing is: doesn't matter what you need it for. if it _were_ programmatically possible to turn on location access, the whole concept of turning it off would be pointless. so no, there isn't any _designed_ way to do it. but - maybe _ask_ the user to enable location access?

Comment: @BIK If you control the machine, why not use available config management tooling (GPO/MDM/SCCM) to ensure Location services is always on?

Comment: @Mathias  The code does run on the company's own workforce laptops, but they are under their control.

Comment: @BIK, what do you mean about the location on windows, something like gps? Is it windows settings location?

Comment: @Jack  Yes GPS location